# Ускорение поиска по ключевым словам DRF api PostgeSQL

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch

Ребят, пожалуйста, нид хелп!

Есть апи, в котором нужно реализовать поиск по ключевым словам. Сейчас есть полнотекстовый поиск postgeSQL, но в 550000 записей (и поиску по огромному количеству слов) - поиск занимает 3 минуты, что не удовлетворяет потребность.

Хочу подключить elasticksearch, возможно поможет. Но, на серверах РФ не дает скачать пакеты. Есть варианты подключить? Какие еще варианты есть ускорить поиск